# Write Failure on sending video to youtube flash player

Tags: c#, youtube

I'm having a problem with a youtube cache I'm trying to make (my internet connection is really slow). It works by detecting if a videoplayback page is requested and saves the response to the disk. It works fine with lightspark and the html5 player on FireFox, but when I try it on Google Chrome I get a Write Failure in RespCacheCallback.

I have the source [here](http://pastebin.com/FTbg7j1j) as it is too long to be posted with the question.

Comment: perhaps you should post the portion of code where you are getting the Write Failure in RespCacheCallback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the range to the ID created in the program when I searched the cache, which meant that the program tried to send the entire video when a small portion was requested, which made the player close the connection. That was fixed by adding this method to MainClass

```
static bool TryGetRange (string url, out string range)
{
    int index = url.IndexOf ("&range=");
    if (index == -1) {
        range = null;
        return false;
    }
    index += 7;
    int len = url.IndexOf ('&',index) - index;
    range = url.Substring (index,len);
    return true;
}
```

This method checks if the `range` parameter is present in the url, and then gets the value of it.
Then adding this code before `if(File.Exists (requestData.Signature + "_done"))`

```
string range;
if(TryGetRange (requestString, out range))
{       
    requestData.Signature += range;
}
```

This adds the range to the signature if the range parameter is detected